# Detecting inconsistent revisions of shared sources in SVN

Tags: svn

I have an SVN repository containing several components:

- LibraryA
- LibraryB - depends on LibraryA
- Application - depends on LibraryB and LibraryA

More detailed structure (branches and tags are not related to the problem):

- LibraryA

  - LibraryA_code
- LibraryB

  - LibraryB_code
  - svn:externals to a fixed revision R1 of LibraryA_code
- Application

  - Application_code
  - svn:externals to a fixed revision R2 of LibraryA_code
  - svn:externals to a fixed revision R3 of LibraryB_code

The problem I'm trying to solve is automatic detection of situation when R2 differs from R1 (breaking expectations of LibraryB_code) and notification about this (e.g. build failure).

I'll describe in an answer the only solution which I see for now, but I hope for something more elegant :)

Environment: Windows, Visual Studio, SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify the `svn:externals` property of *Library B* and commit this change, you create a new revision of *Library B*. This means, the *Application* repository is still consistent. You 
only need to worry when you modify an `svn:externals` property of *Application* itself.

This case can be dealt with in a [repository hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) for the *Application* repository. That hook checks out the specified revision of *Library B* to a temporary directory and compares its required version of *Library A* with that of the version required by the application. See [Repository Hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.reposhooks.html) for a list of available hooks.

Comment: Cool :) Have you heard about usage of such approach in other projects? If there is some widespread implementation it would be better to use it. AFAIK hooks are not stored _in_ repository, so this part of logic will not be part of history, backups, etc. and cannot be viewer by people without access to SVN server, thus it would be good to have as little customness as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Store for each library a file with required revision for each dependency. Add a post-build event which compares these revisions with results of "svnversion" and breaks build if any check fails.

Drawbacks:

1. requires installed command-line svn client (while developer may be happy with TortoiseSVN alone
2. doesn't work for exported sources, only for checked out working copies